# WPF ContentControl Content does not switch to new path of User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, path, contentcontrol

I have the following code to switch content of `ContentControl` in WPF. I am passing it a value of path of User Control page, but it does not load the new page.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public void SwitchPage(string pagePath)
{
    MainContent.Content = pagePath;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**
`MainWindow` contains the following `ContentControl` declaration:

```
<ContentControl Name="MainContent" Content="{Binding ElementName=DemoItemsListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" />
```

Following is the button which fires the event to pass the Url (User Control Path) to the function:

**MenuLinks.xaml**

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domain:MenuLink}">
    <Button Name="ImageButton" ToolTip="Wiki Article" ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0" 
        Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
        Click="Button_Click"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Url}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon x:Name="PackIcon" Kind="BookOpenVariant" />
            <TextBlock Margin="8 0 0 0" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignBody1TextBlock}"
                Text="{Binding Label, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

The button calls the `Button_Click` function in MenuLinks.xaml.cs code-behind file as following, which calls the `SwitchPage` function in `MainWindow`:

**MenuLinks.xaml.cs**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button _myButton = (Button)sender;
    string value = _myButton.CommandParameter.ToString();
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    window.SwitchPage(value);
}
```

Comment: Don't do `new MainWindow()`, instead do `(Window.GetWindow(_myButton) as MainWindow).SwitchPage(value)`.

Comment: That worked Thanks. Now `ContentControl.Content` is only showing the path of user control, not the actual user control. However, i did the following; `            MainContent.Content = new Products();' where Products() is the UserControl i want to dissplay.  Can you please tell me how can i cast `Products` which is a string to `new Products()` which is like a function as a value for `MainContent.Content`.

Comment: I solved it. CommandParameter takes value of object and passes that to a function. I changed the Button_Click and SwitchPage functions to work with object instead of string and it now works fine and loads a different user control when i press the buttons.